# How to give unique id to table rows in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to give different IDs to table rows, so that when I click on the first row, it'll show "selectedRow: 1" on console. Click on the second row, it'll show "selectedRow: 2"

Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
<tbody>
  {this.testData.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <tr onClick={this.handler} key={i} >
        <td>{item.name}</td>
        <td>{item.age}</td>
        <td>{item.address}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  })}
</tbody>

handler=(e)=>{
  let selectedRow = e.target.id //doesn't work
  console.log("selectedRow:", selectedRow)
}
```

Comment: A key is not the id of the element but an identifier that helps react identify modified elements (https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html). `<tr id={i} />` would give the target id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that to work you would need to give every `tr` an `id` attribute, but it would be better if you just straight up pass that id to the function, like so:

```
<tr onClick={() => this.handler(item.id)}>
```

You can also use the index if the items don't have unique IDs.

Now the handler function would receive the id as an argument:

```
handler = (selectedRow) => {
    console.log("selectedRow:", selectedRow)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can I print the id when clicking on the table row in console?

Comment: If you follow this approach, the `handler` function would receive the id as a parameter. `handler = (id) => console.log(id)`. I edited the answer to better illustrate this.

Answer (score 0):

For the `tr` onClick we can give our id as we like like `<tr onClick={this.handler(item.id)}>` 
and our handler function will be high level function like below, then we don't require to create function each time

```
handler = id => e => {
console.log(id)

}
```

[Sample code code from sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8koyy6n94l)