# Set state after deleting table data (td) value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have built a `List.js` component that stores all the appointments.

A list of all the appointments is displayed in a table and a button allows to delete an appointment and send an email as confirmation.

Each row will contain a student/counsellor email according to the user type. I would like to get that email when I delete a row (a `<td>` in `<tr>`) and set the state to that email so I can send an email using the state as the recipient.

This is the component code (including just relevant bits - will update if needed):

```js
// imports

export class Appointments extends Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
  };

  static propTypes = {
    // propsTypes...
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // calling some async func
  }

  // other func

  getAppointmentEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };

  deleteAppointmentEmail = (appointment) => {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    const message = "...";
    const email = {
      message,
      sender: "example@gmail.com",
      recipient: this.state.email,
    };
    console.log(email);
    // this.props.sendEmail(email);
  };

  render() {
    const { isCounselor } = this.props.clients;

    const studentHeader = <th>Student Contact</th>;
    const counselorHeader = <th>Counselor Contact</th>;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h4 className="text-center mt-3">Appointments</h4>
        <br />
        <table className="table table-striped mt-3">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Time</th>
              <th>Location</th>
              {isCounselor ? studentHeader : counselorHeader}
              <th />
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.props.appointments.map((appointment) => (
              <tr key={appointment.id}>
                <td>{appointment.title}</td>
                <td>{appointment.date}</td>
                <td>{`${appointment.start_time.slice(0, 5)} -
                ${appointment.end_time.slice(0, 5)}`}</td>
                <td>{appointment.location}</td>
                <td name="email" value={this.state.email}>
                  {isCounselor
                    ? this.getStudentContact(appointment.student)
                    : this.getCounselorContact(appointment.counselor)}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.getAppointmentEmail;
                      this.props.deleteAppointment(appointment.id);
                      this.deleteAppointmentEmail(appointment);
                    }}
                    className="btn btn-danger"
                  >
                    {""}
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  // ...
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { // ... })(Appointments);
```

I have tried to add `value={this.state.email}`/`value={email}` to the `<td>` but it is not working.

I am also wondering whether `getAppointmentEmail` has been built correctly and if calling it in the `onClick` of the delete button is correct?

Could you please advise? Thank you for your help, it is appreciated!

Comment: Assigning the mail state to the input doesnt work because you initiate the state in a wrong way. You should go through the react tutorials again.

Comment: @Aaron, just confused on how to change a state after clicking a button of a specific row.

Comment: what is the json structure of `appointment variable`?

Comment: Again as I said, read again through the docs. For your problem: use a click-event handler and when its clicked get the id of your row and change the state. This really is a beginner friendly problem. I will do the googling for you

Comment: For getting the row: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755420/how-to-give-unique-id-to-table-rows-in-react change the state inside the event handler

Comment: Does `this.getStudentContact` is returning the email?

Comment: @Jagrati - yes, it does!

Comment: @Aaron, thank you - appreciate your help and will give it a go!

Comment: No problem, didnt want to sound harsh at all :D @GRipepi but the best advise I can give you is to try to solve problems yourself and if you run into any errors etc come to stackoverflow. Learning by doing is usually the best way. :)

Comment: @Aaron -  Thank you for your tip! I have just started using React and I am a bit insecure! Trying to finish this project to learn as much as I can. Really appreciate your help and thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the email contact in a variable:

```
this.props.appointments.map(appointment => {
     const email = isCounselor ? this.getStudentContact(appointment.student) : this.getCounselorContact(appointment.counselor);
     return (
            <tr key={appointment.id}>
               //code inside row ...
            </tr>
      );
  })
```

and then on Delete button :

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    this.getAppointmentEmail(email); // pass email inside the function and then set it in state
    this.props.deleteAppointment(appointment.id);
    this.deleteAppointmentEmail(appointment);
  }}
  className="btn btn-danger"
>
  {""}
  Delete
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Where would I declare the email variable? Both ```getStudentUsers``` and ```getCounselorUsers``` take ```appointment``` as parameter which is generated at ```<tr>``` level by ```this.props.appointments.map((appointment) => (...))```

Comment: you can define the email variable inside `map` function  `this.props.appointments.map((appointment) => {const email = "something" return (// your code)}}`